# Razorpay integration in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, razorpay

Could anybody help in integrating Razorpay in xamarin android project.
I tried calling directly the url in webview,but it is getting stuck in checkout page.

Comment: You could try the suggestions in the link below. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103001/razorpay-in-xamarin

Comment: I tried each single thing...but some are not supported in monoandroid and some are not working

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-xamarin-android-binding/ @uncle_scrooge